# Reversibility in physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reversibility

Is our present understanding of the laws of physics fundamentally reversible? Is easy to see that in classical mechanic this is correct, but I can't see it in quantum mechanic. I know that reversibility only applies to closed systems, but I could make such a system containing my physical system and someone who measures a certain property of this system. This should be a closed system, but when it gets measured, the wave function that describes the system change, and you can not know with certainty what was the state of the system before the measure. Is this still a reversible process?

Comment: Quantum mechanics of a closed system is perfectly reversible. If in your system there are measure processes, then you have to include the measuring apparatus in the system. The total of the system and the measuring apparatus evolves unitarily and therefore in an invertible fashion, but the restricted system alone does not and its dynamics is irreversible in general.

Comment: @yuggib I've never fully understood this claim (I may need to search PSE to find out). How can the laws be reversible when the wave function from which an entangled/coherent particle can't be automatically generated from its surroundings? It seems to me like the system in reverse is far too chaotic to make any predictions at all. How do you go from coherent particles back to a wave function?

Comment: @TrixieWolf I don't understand your comment, sorry. If the system and the apparatus are in interaction, their dynamics will couple the two parts. So even if you start with an entangled/tensor *global* state (entangled for me means it is not a tensor product of two parts, one for each part, tensor that it is a tensor product), the action of the total dynamics will change the structure of the state in a way that it may change from entangled to tensor or vice versa.

Comment: @yuggib Are you saying that particles maintain information about the wavefunction after they collapse/entangle? I'm basically asking how you play back the movie to trace a detected particle back to its source. At the moment a particle is detected, how can you trace it back to where it came from when it was part of a wave function? (Clearly I'm missing a lot of math here and just need to read up, but any encouragement toward the right paradigm would be useful.)

Comment: @TrixieWolf The point is that you can't focus on the particle alone and have reversibility. If you focus on the particle alone in a measure process, then the process is irreversible. On the contrary, if you consider the whole system "particle + measure instrument", the dynamics is reversible. If after the measurement the whole system is described by the product of a state for the particle and one for the instrument (unentangled), using the reversible evolution of the whole system backwards you get the original complete state before measurement. Of course such state is usually entangled.

Comment: @yuggib That response was *incredibly* enlightening for me. Thank you!

Comment: @TrixieWolf You're welcome, glad to help ;-)